# A better for loop without a break;

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, break

I was wondering if there was a better alternative then using this break implementation. I'm trying to improve my abilities and the following does indeed work. Its just that i keep hearing about Break; as being the easy way out and produces potential spaghetti code which hasn't happened here but still.

```
public void getWoodSoldRecently(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -2);
    for(Tree t : theTrees){
        if(t.getSimpleDateSold().getTime().after(cal.getTime()) && t.getHasBeenSold()==true){
            treesSold.add(t);
            System.out.println(t.getTreeId() + " " + t.getTreeType());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Nothing sold in the last 2 weeks");
            break; //Stop the above
        }
    }
}
```

Without the break the "Nothing sold in the last 2 weeks" would output the amount stored in the array.

Comment: Can you post links to where people are being critical of `break`?

Comment: What's with the Trees?  And why do you want to stop processing the rest of the Trees if one hasn't been sold?

Comment: The loop stops at the first tree which don't satisfy the test "date  in the last 2 weeks and Sold". Are you sure?

Comment: Currently, you check every tree in the collection until you find one where the if condition is false (i.e. one that has not been sold). As soon as you find a tree that hasn't been sold you break. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @PaulBellora There is a large number of debates on this very site about `Break;` being bad practice.

Comment: well if his trees are sorted by date, then maybe he can safely assume that once one has not been found, no others will satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Melky I believe you - but I think it would help the question to point to them.

Comment: @Melky: Those arguments against `break` were mostly made by rabidly anti-goto zealots who see any non-`if`, non-loop control statement (particularly `break` and `continue`, and any `return` before the end of a function, and in some cases even `throw`) as "goto in disguise", ignoring the fact that *all* flow control statements are just wrappers around `goto`.  Consider them the crackpots they are, and don't pay them too much attention.  If `break` does exactly what you need it to, then use it.

Comment: @cHao Thank you its just that using the internet as your only source and maybe a few books for learning. Isn't easy when everyone has their own idea on how good coding practices should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you arent doing anything after the break, if it occours. You might aswell replace it with return.

```
public void getWoodSoldRecently(){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -2);
for(Tree t : theTrees){
    if(t.getSimpleDateSold().getTime().after(cal.getTime()) && t.getHasBeenSold()==true){
        treesSold.add(t);
        System.out.println(t.getTreeId() + " " + t.getTreeType());
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Nothing sold in the last 2 weeks");
        return; //Exit function
    }
}
```

}

I personally have no broblem with breaks, however return forces you to encapsulate code into more functions, wich is **always** good.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you don't actually want to break here anyway. Surely you want to just keep going with the rest of the trees - just because you find *one* tree which doesn't match your condition (e.g. it's not been sold), does that really mean there can't be any matching ones later in your collection?

Your method is distinctly strange anyway, in terms of being a `get` method which doesn't *return* anything, but adds values to an existing collection. *That's* the first thing I'd change.

Comment: You are indeed correct about this, I do actually have an if statement that does what you say but didn't include it here. I haven't gotten used to naming conventions just yet and based my get method on if it has outputted and gathering data.

Comment: @Melky: It's hard to give you advice on one situation when you only show a different one. There's no way of telling what I (or any other answerer) would do with your *real* code, based only on this non-representative code.

Answer (score 0):

Break is not bad by definition-it can be misused but the way you are using it is allowed.
You can considered replacing the break with a return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't this using `break` in your example will result into any issue. Still posting one possible workaround(avoid break):

```
   boolean bContinue = true;
   int iSize = theTrees.size();
   for(int indx=0; indx < iSize && bContinue; indx++){
    Tree t  = theTrees.get(indx);
    if(t.getSimpleDateSold().getTime().after(cal.getTime()) 
        && t.getHasBeenSold()==true){
        treesSold.add(t);
        System.out.println(t.getTreeId() + " " + t.getTreeType());
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Nothing sold in the last 2 weeks");
        bContinue = false;//This will stop the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a foreach loop that doesn't enable you to use conditional parameters. If you convert it into a for loop you'll be better off:

```
boolean loopContinue = true;

for(int i = 0; i < theTrees.size() && loopContinue; i++) {
        Tree t = theTrees.get(i);
        if(t.getSimpleDateSold().getTime().after(cal.getTime()) && t.getHasBeenSold()==true){
            treesSold.add(t);
            System.out.println(t.getTreeId() + " " + t.getTreeType());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Nothing sold in the last 2 weeks");
            loopContinue = false; //Stop the above
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT & Clarification: I say "better off" meaning you'll have more control of your loop. As others have said using `break` isn't inherently bad.

Comment: I prefer the `break` version over this, definitely.

Comment: This is even worse than `break` -- now you have a magic variable.

Comment: Yes you do, but I'm answering his question as it was posted. He was looking for alternatives. The variable is included simply for readability while you could completely write it to not include the if statement's conditional in the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Work with an Iterator:

```
public void getWoodSoldRecently(){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -2);
Iterator itr = theTrees.iterator();
boolen b = true;
while (itr.hasNext() && b == true) {
        if(t.getSimpleDateSold().getTime().after(cal.getTime()) && t.getHasBeenSold()==true){
            treesSold.add(t);
            System.out.println(t.getTreeId() + " " + t.getTreeType());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Nothing sold in the last 2 weeks");
            b = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Magic variables are far worse than `break`, IMO.  At least when i see a `break`, i *know* i'm jumping elsewhere.

Comment: you are probably right, furthermore in this case you need two more variables. But the question was how to avoid the `break`. An this is one example.